# As we call "1/x" inverse x, how we name " -1/x"?

Tags: functions

Just as $\sin(x)$ represents some $f(x)$, where the $f(x) = \text{opposite/hypotenuse}$
and it seems redundant to create another function $\csc(x) = \text{the inverse of } \sin(x)$

As we call $\displaystyle\frac{1}{f(x)}$  inverse $f(x)$, then how we name $\displaystyle\frac{-1}{f(x)}$?

:|

PS: i have corrected the miswriting of $\csc(x)$.  :)

---

**An extension on the question.**

The structure of the inverse of $f$, take
$f(x) = (1+x)/(x-1)$ and $g(x) = (1-x)/(1+x)$,
both are identical to $f$ (or $g$) itself.
To name them respectively and be sure to take account of the property of $F(x) = (1+x)/(1-x)$ or $G(x) = (x-1)/(1+x)$.

Comment: The "additive inverse" of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$?  When we just say "inverse" we typically mean "multiplicative inverse" -- but in a field (like the set of real numbers), elements have additive inverses and multiplicative inverses (the latter only if they are nonzero).  So, $2$ has "additive inverse" $-2$ and it has "multiplicative inverse" $\frac{1}{2}$.  The "additive inverse" of $\frac{1}{2}$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Or 'the opposite'.

Comment: I would prefer to use the word reciprocal.

Comment: Cosine is neither the inverse nor the reciprocal of sine, so your example is not useful in understanding what the Question is.

Comment: additive inverse is well, and it could made simpler. Not a compound    one

Answer (score 2):

TylerHG is correct, I just thought I would try to explain it with different phrasing.

"Inverse" is an ambiguous term *by itself*.  We need to know *what* we're doing the inverse of.  An "inverse" is an object that, when applied to the original object, we get the "identity."  In layman's terms, I like to think of the "inverse" as something that "undoes."

However, just knowing we can "undo" something is *worthless* unless we know *what* we're undoing!  That's why we must use the term "inverse" *with another term* that specifies *what* we're "undoing."

Thus, we call $\frac{1}{x}$ the **multiplicative inverse**, because multiplying by $\frac{1}{x}$ "undoes" multiplying by $x$.

Similarly, we call $(-x)$ the **additive inverse** of $x$ because adding $(-x)$ "undoes" adding $x$.

This extends to functions as well--we call $f^{-1}$ the **functional inverse** (or the **inverse function**) of $f$ because applying $f^{-1}$ "undoes" applying $f$.  We can say the same about **inverse matrices** and **inverse operations** in general.

Inverses are a *really* interesting part of mathematics.  If you want to learn more about them, consider reading a book on (or taking a course in) *Abstract Algebra*.  You will learn a *lot* about what *exactly* an "inverse" is.

---

To address the particular scenario at hand, one could call $\frac{-1}{x}$ the "additive inverse of the multiplicative inverse of $x$."  A bit shorter is the "additive inverse of the reciprocal of $x$" (but that assumes you know that the reciprocal *is* the multiplicative inverse).

Shorter still is "the **negative reciprocal** of $x$," because "negative" refers to the "additive inverse" and "reciprocal" refers to the multiplicative inverse.  I use this term when discussing this quantity a lot.

Comment: Negative reciprocal or opposite reciprocal is right by an entry in mathwords _[link](http://www.mathwords.com/n/negative_reciprocal.htm)_  .As the perp.(=perpendicular) lines have slopes of identical form of "-1/x",to name "-1/x" perp(x) is good for something.

Comment: @TeaSig I have *never* heard "opposite reciprocal."  Furthermore "opposite" is a bad term for the same reason as "inverse"--with respect to *what* is this opposite?  (It needs to be specified.)  I honestly don't think this term is common enough to require any further popularized designation.  (e.g. a paper could possibly say "Let $\text{perp}(x) = \frac{-1}{x}$," but there's no point in naming it that and teaching it to a bunch of students.)

Answer (score 1):

One needs to be more clear when talking about inverses. Their are functional inverses such as the "arc" trig functions, multiplicative inverses, and additive inverses. $\cos$ is not the inverse of $\sin$. The multiplicative inverse of $\sin$ is $\csc$ which in the sense of triangles is "hypotenuse over opposite." And cosine would be "adjacent of hypotenuse." The functional inverse of sine is $\arcsin$. Now as for you question, $1/f$ is the multiplicative inverse of $f$ as $f/f=1$. The function $-1/f$ is the additive inverse of $1/f$ as $-1/f+1/f=0$.

Comment: the additive inverse of "1/f" is defined by the equation "-1/f + 1/f = 0"  ;  the multiplicative inverse of "f" is defined by the equation "f*1/f = 1";

Comment: i think it's a pattern of how the name of some frequently used function was created.And it's scientific , but not a good one.